# Problem with basic auth & json content in requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am a data analyst moonlighting in some web development, so apologies if this an obvious question, however I couldn't find a direct answer amongst previous questions or requests documentation.

I am trying to access data from an API that requires both basic auth and a content-type: application/json header. I have got this working in postman, but can't transfer to the python requests library - which returns 401.

I have tried passing in the login details (Username, password) as a tuple / list to the relevant dictionary key, however that doesn't work.

What am I missing?

```
import requests

headers={'Authorization': 'Basic <credentials>', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.get("https://data.donorfy.com/api/v1/LFJZWVODI2/constituents/ExternalKey/1", headers=headers)

r.json()
```

Comment: You're leaking your credentials in that Base-64 encoded string.

Comment: Thanks - have changed. Wasn't sure what the protocol was for fully reproducible examples.

Comment: Look here: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/ . You can export the HTTP call from postman to python/requests code